# Not able to publish azure python function app with external dependencies (not in index)

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, python-wheel

I have an simple python module [AdditionalLibrary](https://github.com/PawelBogdan/AdditionalLibrary), I do not want to publish it nowhere public. I have also an azure python serverless function app [ExamplePythonServerlessFunction](https://github.com/PawelBogdan/ExamplePythonServerlessFunction) I want to publish on azure.

I followed official documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python

and an out-dated page https://prmadi.com/install-python-modules-on-azure-app-services/

Finally I have a `wheelhouse` directory in my azure function project containing `*.whl` files for every dependency I need. I try to put additional flags to my `requirments.txt` file to use `wheelhouse` directory instead of index. This is content of my `requirments.txt` file.

```
--no-index --find-links file://wheelhouse
Additional-Library==1.0
azure-functions==1.0.0b4
azure-functions-worker==1.0.0b6
grpcio==1.20.1
grpcio-tools==1.20.1
protobuf==3.6.1
six==1.11.0
```

During publishing the app:

```sh
$ func azure functionapp publish ${APP_NAME} --build-native-deps
```

I get an error:

```
  Url 'file://wheelhouse' is ignored: it is neither a file nor a directory.
```

and I am not able to install dependencies. Is that way is correct? How can I install some additional dependencies to azure function app.

Any help and advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been doing this:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '../../../az/Lib/site-packages')))
from azure.storage.cloudstorageaccount import CloudStorageAccount,AccountPermissions,Services,ResourceTypes
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
```

so you can just create a directory in your function and add it to path and import modules from that path.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I think it's quite ugly solution;) Isn't there any prittier one?