# Use own packages (Artifact) in Azure function?

Tags: python, package, azure-functions, azure-artifacts

I want to use a packages deploy on azure artifact in an azure function

locally it was simple : just update the pip.ini, and the installation from requirements works great, I can launch my azure function locally, all is working

But how can I do it when I deploy it? maybe I need to put a pip.ini somewhere in my main folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally find the solution :

go to your azure function, and open the command

here launch the different command :

```
mkdir pipconfig
cd pipconfig
```

now right your pip.ini with :

```
echo "[global]" > pip.ini
echo "extra-index-url=https://XXXXX" >> pip.ini
```

with the last url link to your artifact
now you have created your pip.ini in your azure function, go to your environement variable and create :

```
PIP_CONFIG_FILE with value /home/pipconfig/pip.ini
```

and restart your function : you can publish as always and you can import your private artifact

hope it will help other people

Comment: Hi kilag, I'm glad that you have found the solution. Since you have solved the  problem by this solution, you can mark yourself answer as "accepted". This can be beneficial to other community members.

Comment: Just add `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` to your app settings under configuration in the portal, along with your URL. Cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

From your Function in the Azure Portal, navigate to its configuration blade. Then add under the 'Application Settings` tab click 'New Application Setting'. Provide the below as the key:

```
PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL
```

With the value set as your URL you want to use instead.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#custom-dependencies

Any `pip` flag can be set as an environment variable, example

```
--trusted-host
```

can be set as

```
PIP_TRUSTED_HOST
```

Just prefix `PIP_` then the flag in capitals with `-` changed to `_`

Answer (score 2):

Since you have generated `requirements.txt` file and it includes all of the info of the packages in your function project. You just need to deploy your function project(with `requirements.txt`) to azure. It will install the packages according to the `requirements.txt` automatically. For more information about deploy the python function to azure, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli?pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=bash%2Cbrowser#deploy-the-function-project-to-azure).

**Update:**

As you mentioned your package is not a public package in your comments. You can try to use this command below:

```
func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME> --build local
```

This command will build your project locally and then deploy it to azure.(But I'm not sure if this command can work fine because it also read from the `requirements.txt` file)

If the "build local" command doesn't work, you need to use docker, please refer to the steps in below screenshot:
[image]

Here is a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#publishing-to-azure) for further information about the steps above.

Comment: yes but my packages is in the requirements, but it is not a public package, it is come just from my artifact
so when I try the deployment, it says :
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MyPackages==0.0.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MyPackages==0.0.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
so it seems during deployment my pip.ini is not use

Comment: Hi @kilag, I have updated my answer, please have a try.

Comment: Hi @Hury Shen,
I have use the Custom dependencies solution, but there is two pb : 
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding'
this one appear on the portal, currently investigate because there is no problem on local
the second is more about deployment, before I just have to click on button in visual studio, now, I need to open a terminal to deploy, looking if there is a way to do it with the visual studio button (it is really more convenient)

Comment: @kilag For your first problem, I think you may refer to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011364/not-able-to-publish-azure-python-function-app-with-external-dependencies-not-in)(but this solution maybe not perfect). For second question, I think there isn't a button can replace the command, but if the new solution works fine, I think we do not need to use "no build" comand.